# Cannot do foreach in collection defined with extra pivot variable - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.4

I just cannot get a list of models in a collection. Seems to be a simple problem, but I just can't guess the right solution.

I have a pivot table with 3 foreign keys:

`TABLE leadsupplier_product`

```
id | lead_id | supplier_id | product_id

4  |  128    |  2048       |  8
3  |  120    |  2048       |  7
4  |  120    |  2048       |  8
```

In my `Supplier' model I have defined this relation:

```
public function products()
{
    // ->where('leadsupplier_product.lead_id', $leadid)
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Product::class, 'leadsupplier_product', 'supplier_id', 'product_id')->withPivot('lead_id','id');
}
```

### What I try to get:

In a given lead template I want to cycle through models with `foreach` loop

So in template for  $lead = 120;
I have this:

#### counting

```
{{$o->products()->wherePivot('lead_id', $lead->id)->count()}}
```

and it works as expected (I get the proper number of models)

```
// no `()` after the relation name
{{$o->products->wherePivot('lead_id', $lead->id)->count()}}
```

I get `ErrorException in Macroable.php line 74: Method wherePivot does not exist.` Why?

#### foreaching

But in my `foreach` loop  I was unable to get the collection printed:

```
// no objects printed
  @foreach($o->products()->where('leadsupplier_product.lead_id', $lead->id) as $ps)
      <a class="btn btn-sm bg-greenish">abc {{$ps->id}} </a> 
       LbyP:{{$ps->pivot->lead_id}} LS: {{$ps->pivot->id}}   L:{{$lead->id}}
  @endforeach

// no objects printed
@foreach($o->products()->wherePivot('lead_id', $lead->id) as $ps)
      <a class="btn btn-sm bg-greenish">abc {{$ps->id}} </a> 
       LbyP:{{$ps->pivot->lead_id}} LS: {{$ps->pivot->id}}   L:{{$lead->id}}
@endforeach
```

Now, if I define a relation with a parameter

```
public function productsThisLead($leadid)
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Product::class, 'leadsupplier_product', 'supplier_id', 'product_id')->withPivot('lead_id','id')->where('leadsupplier_product.lead_id', $leadid);
}


// I get no results in the `foreach` loop
  @foreach($o->productsThisLead($lead->id) as $ps)

      <a class="btn btn-sm bg-greenish">abc {{$ps->id}} </a> 
       LbyP:{{$ps->pivot->lead_id}} LS: {{$ps->pivot->id}}   L:{{$lead->id}}

  @endforeach
```

Help!

#### what I need

- How I can pass a variable into the relation defined in model?
- or just how to define the relation so that it would output a collection?

---

#### My dirty solution

I just add an extra `@if` condition inside the loop

```
  @foreach($o->products as $ps)
    @if($ps->pivot->lead_id == $lead->id)
      <a class="btn btn-sm bg-greenish">abc {{$ps->id}} </a> 
       LbyP:{{$ps->pivot->lead_id}} LS: {{$ps->pivot->id}}   L:{{$lead->id}}
    @endif
  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Two parts to your question...

First part..

```
{{$o->products()->wherePivot('lead_id', $lead->id)->count()}}
and it works as expected (I get the proper number of models)

// no `()` after the relation name
{{$o->products->wherePivot('lead_id', $lead->id)->count()}}
I get ErrorException in Macroable.php line 74: Method wherePivot does not exist. Why?
```

When you call the relationship without (), it will try to return the relationship value... When you call it with () it will return the query builder object that you can continue builiding on... like you are doing...

Now, when doing that, it must be a complete query builder statement... don't forger ->get() ... like so... That should work...

```
$o->products()->wherePivot('lead_id', $lead->id)->get()
```

This will return the collection you are looking for...

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I will test it in a couple of hours.